# Overriding random points in file

Tags: ruby, regex, replace, sed

I want to overwrite portions of a file based on a regex pattern. The ruby script will look for `camelCase` variable names and convert them to something like `background-color`. I have a list of all variables to convert (the keys) and what they need to be changed to (the values):

```
variables = {
    "backgroundColor" => "background-color",
    "fontSize" => "font-size",
    "fontFamily" => "font-family",
    "fontColor" => "font-color",
    "formFont" => "form-font",
    "linkColor" => "link-color",
    "linkHoverColor" => "link-hover-color",
    "linkDecoration" => "link-decoration",
    "headingFamily" => "heading-family",
    "headingColor" => "heading-color",
    "baseWidth" => "base-width",
    "baseColWidth" => "base-col-width",
    "baseGutterWidth" => "base-gutter-width",
    "isFluid" => "is-fluid",
    "baseColCount" => "base-col-count",
    "tabletWidth" => "tablet-width",
    "mobilePortraitWidth" => "mobile-portrait-width",
    "mobileLandscapeWidth" => "mobile-landscape-width"
}
```

I have [a working shell script](http://pastebin.com/hBbbFTQ5):

```
sed -i '' "s/${keys[i]}/${values[i]}/g" _MYconfig.scss
```

I am trying to translate this into Ruby. I tried reading the file line by line, but the lines in the file don't correspond to the items in the collection. Something like this will not work:

```
File.open("_skeleton.config.scss", "r+") do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
        # use gsub here
    end
end
```

Then I drew inspiration from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ryenus/1518596), and tried:

```
variables.each do |key, value|
    %x(ruby -p -e "gsub /#{key}/, '#{value}' #{Dir.pwd}#{filename}")
end
```

but I can't seem to get it to work. I can't figure out how to write at random points in a file like `sed`. I can't figure out how to iterate through `variables` using the ruby version of sed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for each key:

```
newkey = oldkey.gsub(/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/, '-').downcase
```

**Explanation**

- The regex matches positions (not characters) located between the change in case by using a lookbehind and a lookahead
- `(?<=[a-z])` asserts that the previous char is lowercase
- `(?=[A-Z])` asserts that the next char is uppercase
- the `gsub` replaces that position with a `-`
- we `downcase` the result

To see the replacement before the downcase, see the substitutions at the bottom of this [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/vT3sP2/1).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
# read all lines of the file into an array
file_lines = File.readlines("_skeleton.config.scss", "r+")
new_file_lines = []

# gsub each line with all your matches
file_lines.each do |line|
   new_line = line
   variables.each do |key, value|
     new_line = new_line.gsub /#{key}/, value
   end
   new_file_lines << new_line
end

# then truncate the old file and write back the set of newlines
File.open("_skeleton.config.scss", "w") do |f|
   new_file_lines.each do |line|
      f.write line
   end
end
```

note: not tested, may contain bugs...